# Update chart for each single for loop

Tags: excel, for-loop, auto-update, vba

Im trying to implement auto-update data with the chart everytime i click the button. The function is inside the for loop and will be executed to obtain the data from another workbook. After it success obtain the data, the chart will be created, but the chart only created after the all loop has finish executed. Is there any other way to do this? each single loop will update data and chart. The chart viewed on another workbook.

this is my code

```
Sub LiveUpdate_Button1_Click()
Dim x As Long
For x = 0 To 10
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5"))
Call Data_1
Call Data_2
Call Data_3
Next x

'Call SingleClick
  ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Workbooks("graph.xlsx").RefreshAll
End Sub
```

Data_1 - Data_3 currently have the same code just different range.

```
Sub Data_3()
Dim x As Long
'For x = 0 To 10
Dim iLast As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim targetlastrow As Long, sourcelstrow As Long
Dim Sourcelastcol As Long
Dim source As Worksheet
Dim target As Worksheet
Dim InputRng As Range
Dim OutRng As Range
Dim xRow As Integer
Dim count As Integer
Dim count1 As Integer
Dim test As String
Dim LookupWB As Workbook
Dim pth As String
Dim pth2 As String
Dim pth3 As String
Dim lotNo As String
Dim field As String
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LiveUpdate").Activate
Range("AH16", "AK25").ClearContents
Range("AF123", "AI162").ClearContents
Range("AK123", "AM162").ClearContents


 pth = Sheets("LiveUpdate").Cells(1, 3).Value 'Select folder path
 pth2 = Sheets("LiveUpdate").Cells(1, 4).Value 'Select file path
 pth3 = "=LEFT(D1, LEN(D1)-25)"  'Trim to obtain Item Type
 Sheets("LiveUpdate").Cells(1, 5).Value = pth3
 Sheets("LiveUpdate").Cells(16, 5).Value = "=RIGHT((LEFT(D1, LEN(D1)-4)), LEN(LEFT(D1, LEN(D1)-4))-18)"



'Set LookupWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=pth)
Set source = Workbooks(pth2).Sheets(1)
Set target = Workbooks("New Microsoft Excel Worksheet").Sheets("LiveUpdate")

field = target.Cells(9, 39) 'Select field
'source.Activate

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LiveUpdate").Activate
iLast = source.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Set InputRng = source.Range(field & iLast - 60 & ":" & field & iLast) 'Which field data to take
Set InputRng = InputRng.Columns(1)
Set ConRng = source.Range("C2:C" & iLast) 'Condition
Set ConRng = ConRng.Columns(1)
Set DateRng = source.Range("D2:E2") 'Date
Set DateRng = DateRng.Columns(1)
Set DateRng1 = DateRng.Columns(2)

'To set number of row with pass value
For i = 1 To iLast
        xValue = InputRng.Cells(i + 1)
        xCon = ConRng.Cells(i + 1)
        If xCon = "PASS" And Not IsEmpty(xValue) Then
        count1 = count1 + 1
        End If
    Next i

'target.Cells(12, 11) = (count1 / iLast) * 100
'target.Cells(13, 11) = 100 - target.Cells(12, 11).Value
Set OutRng = target.Range("$AH$16") 'Field to view output

xDate = DateRng.Cells(1)
xTime = DateRng1.Cells(1)
Sheets("LiveUpdate").Cells(16, 31).Value = xDate
Sheets("LiveUpdate").Cells(16, 32).Value = xTime

xCol = 4  ' To set how many row per item
k = 0
xRow = 10

'ReDim xArr(1 To xRow, 1 To xRow + 1)
ReDim xArr(1 To xRow + 1, 1 To xCol)
    For i = 0 To InputRng.Cells.count - 1
        xValue = InputRng.Cells(i + 1)
        xCon = ConRng.Cells(i + 1)
        If xCon = "PASS" And k <= 39 And Not IsEmpty(xValue) Then
            iCol = k Mod xCol
            iRow = VBA.Int(k / xCol)
            xArr(iRow + 1, iCol + 1) = xValue
            count = count + 1
        Else
            k = k - 1
        End If
        k = k + 1
    Next
    OutRng.Resize(UBound(xArr, 1), UBound(xArr, 2)).Value = xArr

Range("AF123", "AF" & (123 + xRow - 1)).Value = target.Cells(28, 35) 'to copy all value from G302
Range("AG123", "AG" & (123 + xRow - 1)).Value = target.Cells(28, 36) 'to copy all value from H302
Range("AH123", "AH" & (123 + xRow - 1)).Value = target.Cells(28, 37) 'to copy all value from I302
Range("AK123", "AK" & (123 + xRow - 1)).Value = target.Cells(29, 35) 'to copy all value from G303
Range("AL123", "AL" & (123 + xRow - 1)).Value = target.Cells(29, 36) 'to copy all value from H303


For i = 0 To xRow - 1
    target.Cells(123 + i, 35) = target.Cells(16 + i, 38) 'to copy all value from J16
    target.Cells(123 + i, 39) = target.Cells(16 + i, 39) 'to copy all value from K16
Next i
source.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: please also show your procedures `Data_1` to `3`.

Comment: I have uploaded the code. currently, all data1-data3 has same code but a different range. @ashleedawg